# How to get all the primary key Values using Cursor and add it in Arraylist?

Tags: android

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName _id integer primary key autoincrement,Title varchar ,Description varchar .

My table name look like this.

Please anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest explaining the question a little further, but I believe what you're looking for is a way to iterate through a cursor and get all of the primary keys.  Try something like this:

```
ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();

if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
        ids.add(id);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the below code,
        If suppose the table have two columns as _id and name,while querying the Select      statement we know the columnindex of resulting query.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> keyid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
           int id= 0;
           String name = null
        String statement = "Select * from  " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(statement, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                             id = c.getInt(0);
                     name= c.getString(1);

                             keyid.add(id);
                             names.add(name);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
```